# Disabled "Finish" Button in Android ADT r21.1 New Activity Wizard

Tags: android, eclipse, osx-lion, android-activity, adt

[image: New Activity Wizard]

I fixed [a similar issue after ADT r20](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33859), but this new problem I'm having after updating to r21.1 is slightly different.

I can create new projects, but not a new `Activity`, in any project (new or old), when I try to use any of the templates in the wizard. I tried deleting the Support Library from the SDK Manager, reinstalled, and restarted but that isn't doing the trick for me this time.

The manual method of making an Activity works just fine but the template wizard is handy. Any ideas from others who might've have seen this recently?

- ADT r21.1
- Eclipse Juno 4.2.1
- OS X 10.7.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is supposed to be a Next button, which you would need to click in order to provide details of the activity to be created. Apparently, your Next button was eaten by a grue.

You might consider filing a Tools issue on http://b.android.com with the details that you have provided here.

Comment: Thanks! I just filed [Issue 49972](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=49972 "Disabled “Finish” button / missing "Next" button in New Activity Wizard following update to ADT r21.1").

Answer (score 5):

Use File - New - Other path in menu